# What is the best speech recognition library for Java Micro Edition?

Tags: java, speech-recognition, java-me

What is the best speech recognition library for jme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had luck with CMU's sphinx project.

Comment: isn't sphinx the only library for speech recognition in java?

Comment: It may be... It's the only one I know of...